# How can I reproduce this harmony?

Tags: theory, harmony, composition

In Bury Me by Bayside at about 3:09 (the line that starts with "I want your respect..."), they use a strange dissonant-sounding harmony: [time stamped youtube link](https://youtu.be/zcXl6R63wRo?t=182).

It sounds to me like he's using 3 different vocal tracks to create the harmony, but my ear isn't near good enough to pick out the individual melodies. This harmony is unlike anything I'd heard before, so I'm very curious about what they're doing there. **Is there a formal name for this type of harmony? And how would I reproduce this with an arbitrary lead melody?**

<sup>Disclaimer: I have some knowledge of music theory, but it has definitely been awhile.</sup>

Comment: I think this sounds dissonant because all three voices are going down a chromatic scale, which I guess is a harmony style. The low voice might not (can't pick it out) but the top two certainly do.

Comment: @Legorhin I'm halfway sure one of those voices is "out of tune," which is causing it. But I can't tell what notes are being hit or how I'd make it happen myself.

Comment: I guess it could be quartertones

Comment: It sounds like they inexpertly overdubbed some attempted harmonies and kept the lucky accidents. It sounds pretty much like chaos to me but each to his own. I doubt they could do it again. .  . .

Answer (score 2):

I've determined the actual notes:

[image: Key of d minor]

The middle voice is the main melody. I'm not aware of any formal name for this kind of harmony, but it is certainly dissonant. I agree with PeterJ in that the harmonies are likely a result of lucky accidents. Regardless, each voice moves in a descending manner.

Edit: As Rose F pointed out, the two Gs on “your re-“ are actually G#/Ab

Comment: That's some impressive transcription of some dissonant music. But are you sure about the Gs on "your re-"? They sound like G#/Ab to me (as opposed to G on "-spect", where I agree with you).

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I actually found a "studio chat" they did about this song where they play each voice individually, which may make it easier to find the notes (or check them): https://youtu.be/nb92jB2Iph4?t=439

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at an instrument now to check, but it sounds like harmony in thirds going down chromatically.

It also sounds like an electronic effect. It sounds artificial and that gives it a sort of weirdness. At least for me. Harmonizer effects put me off. They don't have the warmth of real harmonizing. A kind of [uncanniness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley). This may account for the 'out of tune' sense you get.